# Ajax JSON response undefined in prompt field

Tags: javascript, ajax

I don't know what is wrong with my code. I tried to fill javascript prompt with ajax response. Here is my code :

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ url('/dashboard/popfieldexist') }}",
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'POST',
            data: "_token={{ csrf_token() }}&"+"selector="+f1[0].getAttribute('data-file'),
            success: function (response) {
                if(response){
                    getPopfield = response.data.field;
                }else{
                    getPopfield = " ";
                }
            }
        });
        var title = prompt("File name : ", ""+getPopfield+"");
```

[image: undefined]

it display undefined..

Comment: Your `prompt` opens before ajax returns.

Comment: Try instead to `console.log()` it and update us...

Comment: thanks guys. It solved. I thought javascript will execute the script sequences, so I put the prompt after ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ajax call is usually asynchronous. So your prompt is called before the ajax finished.

Try:

```
   $.ajax({
        url: "{{ url('/dashboard/popfieldexist') }}",
        dataType: "json",
        type: 'POST',
        data: "_token={{ csrf_token() }}&"+"selector="+f1[0].getAttribute('data-file'),
        success: function (response) {
            if(response){
                getPopfield = response.data.field;
            }else{
                getPopfield = " ";
            }
            var title = prompt("File name : ", ""+getPopfield+"");
        }
    });
```